# Setup WooCommerce to properly handle inventory with variable product?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am setting up a store that has sells 2 part products (we sell motorcycle mounts and cradles for your gadget) we have 20 different products and 20 different accessories that can be combined with them. Right now we are doing this through variable products. The problem is that is dosen't handle inventory correctly, ultimately I would like to control the inventory on the 20 products and the 20 accessories, so when a combo is purchased it subtracts from both items and if one part is old out it reflects it on the products page. Is there any plugin out their that can handle this or an easy way to code it? Thank you guys so much for any help or ideas.

Comment: Welcome to [WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). Third party plugins are off-topic, see [help/on-topic]. Try the support forums at [WooThemes](http://support.woothemes.com), or [WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce). I'd also encourage you to support the proposed [WooCommerce Q&A site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80132/woocommerce) on StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

Variable products might not be what you're looking for in this case. You can better use product bundles since you're combining products. (Plug-in available through woothemes).